# What will happen if a serial-upvote reputation is lately reversed for this scenario?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

Let's assume at the beginning I have 1 reputation. Another user serially votes my posts up until I get, for example, serial-upvote reputation of 150. Thus my rep becomes 151 in total now.

If I spend this reputation for a bounty of 150 before the system reverses the serial-upvote reputation of 150, what will happen later?

1. The system reverses the serial-upvote reputation of 150 and I get -149 reputation,
2. The system reverses the serial-upvote reputation of 150 and cancel the bounty of 150 so I get 1 reputation,
3. The system does not reverse the serial-upvote reputation of 150 (I am lucky).

Comment: Let's make a try. Who will serially vote my posts up?

Comment: So slick… :-) I think this is rather a question for Meta.SO to be honest.

Comment: @SeanAllred: I need a volunteer to do the serial-upvote.

Comment: Guess: may be `option 1` would be possible,but I would suggest `option 4`: The system gives up :)

Comment: This is very unlikely, unless you want to cheat the system in any way, which is not a good idea, since serial voting reversals get logged and if they're repeated, I think that someone gets notified actively. **My guess: option 4:** you get to 1 rep for the reverse and that's it, therefore you can spend a reputation that you basically don't have on a bounty. But it's only a guess. **NB:** I'm not going to serial-upvote anyone, sorry.

Comment: @tohecz: I also don't need serial-upvote reputation. This question or scenario or experiment should be considered as a fun way to probe the behavior of the system, whether or not it becomes a bug. I and Harish Kumar will do the second experiments next week after all of my offered bounties expired by itself because there is no target right now for the running bounties.

Comment: What would happen if I delete my account? `:)`

Comment: No experiments please: deliberate serial voting is not allowed, whatever the reasons for it. Remember reputation is supposed to be earned for _quality of content on the site_, not who you are. It's also there as a guide to others and to help make things 'work'.

Comment: The time-space continuum will rip all of us a new one.

Comment: @PauloCereda: Nobody can play with PSmith anymore.

Comment: @CodeMocker: oh no! `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is purely speculation, but is the most probable based on other events:

1. You get serially upvoted for +150.
2. You spend it all on a bounty.
3. It is reversed. You get -150 rep, but you have 1, and since rep can't go below 1, you still have 1 rep.
4. A mod refunds the bounty. You now temporarily have 151 rep.
5. Your rep is recalculated, and now you have 1 again. [I'm guessing this will happen pretty quickly.]